# How to validate XML against schema without using exceptions for control flow?

Tags: java, xml, validation, exception, xsd

```
  public static boolean IsValid(InputStream xml, InputStream xsd)
  {
    try
    {
      SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
      Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(xsd));
      Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
      validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
      return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

As you can see exceptions are used for control flow, which I want to change, since it is no good practice, as exceptions should be used only for exceptional cases.
(Maybe one could argue, that it is indeed an execptional case in some contexts, if a xml is not valid... )

The `validate` method has anothe signature `validate(Source source, Result result)`, but taking a look at the `Result` interface did not really help me.

```
/**
 * Set the system identifier for this Result.
 *
 * <p>If the Result is not to be written to a file, the system identifier is optional.
 * The application may still want to provide one, however, for use in error messages
 * and warnings, or to resolve relative output identifiers.</p>
 *
 * @param systemId The system identifier as a URI string.
 */
public void setSystemId(String systemId);

/**
 * Get the system identifier that was set with setSystemId.
 *
 * @return The system identifier that was set with setSystemId,
 * or null if setSystemId was not called.
 */
public String getSystemId();
```

So how can I validate XMLs against Schemas? It doesn't need to be my approach! Was it intended to use `validate` the way I did it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should implement an [`ErrorHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ErrorHandler.html), for example by extending [`DefaultHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html), and register that to your `Validator` by calling [`Validator#setErrorHandler()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/validation/Validator.html#setErrorHandler%28org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler%29).

Your `ErrorHandler` can than record all validation errors (and warnings, if you're interested in them). Don't forget to implement / override the `fatalError(...)` method as well, so that you'll be notified when the document could not be parsed, for example because it is not well-formed.

As long as your `ErrorHandler` doesn't throw any exceptions, neither will the call to `validate()`. Its Javadoc states that it will throw a `SAXException`

> if the `ErrorHandler` throws a `SAXException` or if a fatal error is found and the `ErrorHandler` returns normally.

So it should be possible to validate a document and not rely on exception handling for control flow. As long as you ask your `ErrorHandler` whether it found any errors after having validated the document. Unfortunately, if your document is not well-formed, you'll still have to catch a `SAXParseException`.

Comment: But that wouldn't change the fact that exceptions are used for control flow. So I could basically just leave it how it is, that would be easier.

Comment: @mike Exceptions are meant to allow program to take another route of action, or inform the user, or shut down, or whatever. Use an `ErrorHandler` and catch only `SAXException` that correspond to a stream validation error. Also validation is a step in transformation, it should not be placed in a separate method.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm to strict about exeptions. I placed the validation method in an util class, since I have some xml files that I want to check/deserialize at program start.

Comment: Well I didn't say I like the current approach taken by `javax.xml` package. I prefer to use `Exception`s for, well, exceptional situations, and a not well-formed document is something I would prefer to be able to handle without `Exception`s.

Comment: Thx for your effort. I'm going to consider extending the error handler, or stick with my current approach, since it's adequate for my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The designers of the JAXP validation interface chose to signal a validation failure using an Exception. You may think that's a poor design, but your choice is to use that API the way it is designed, or to find a different API.

Comment: I thought about why they designed it that way. And I can't think of no other way to indicate failure **and** show where the failure happened. A boolean flag would be insufficient.